# Convert a UUID into a GUID and vice versa

Tags: java, hibernate, uuid, guid, endianness

I have this UUID which is changed inside a hqlQuery result when querying a MSSQL database:

```
createQuery("... where UUID = '917f116e-3447-4524-a959-ece721413f93'").list() //finds the right object
```

but returns an object with a modified UUID `6e117f91-4734-2445-a959-ece721413f93`

```
917f116e-3447-4524-a959-ece721413f93 // correct UUID goes into query
6e117f91-4734-2445-a959-ece721413f93 // modified UUID from the resultset
```

now when i do a query with the modified UUID:

```
createQuery("... where UUID = '6e117f91-4734-2445-a959-ece721413f93'").list()
```

i don't find an object.

So i need to convert the modified one back to the original (and also the other way around). I don't know if this is an little vs big endian issue.

Comment: These are simply two different UUIDs, You can't convert one to the other.

Comment: @Henry No, that is different byte-orders within. Standard UUIDs use network byte order (big-endian) for all components, but Microsoft applies little-endian for the first three components (and calls them GUIDs): _"Other systems, notably Microsoft's marshalling of UUIDs in their COM/OLE libraries, use a mixed-endian format, whereby the first three components of the UUID are little-endian, and the last two are big-endian."_ from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: Can't you use parameters instead, I'd expect the UUID to be marshalled correctly in that case (just like when retrieving the value). Otherwise you'll need to write something (or find an existing library) that orders bytes: 0,1,2,3--4,5-6,7--8,9--10,11,12,13,14,15 to 3,2,1,0--5,4--7,6--8,9--10,11,12,13,14,15

Comment: @MarkRotteveel What do you mean?

Comment: You're currently using a literal. SQL Server expects those literals to conform to their expected GUID byte-order, instead of the UUID byte-order. If you'd use a parameter for the value instead of a literal, I'd expect it to be converted correctly, just like it does when retrieving the value.

Comment: Hmm i think this is not possible since we have some external systems relying on the current state... but maybe if. Can you do an example? When i use hibernates `session.get(entityname,uuid)` then the modified uuid is accepted as the right uuid instead of the real one.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ahh, Microsoft ... I learned something new today.

Comment: That is exactly the affect you want. The 'modified' uuid is the same uuid, but in the network byte order (all big-endian) specified in the standard and used by Java, while SQL Server itself uses a combination of little-endian and big-endian byte orders (see my second comment). The Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver does the translation between those two formats for you (but of course not with literals).

Comment: there's one more problem.... the objects in the result set are also with the flipped UUIDs

Answer (score 0):

I make no claim this is the best solution, but this is *a* solution. This should encode big endian into little endian and vice versa.

```java
import java.util.UUID;

// ...

 public static UUID uuidMarshalIntoMSFormat(UUID uuid)
  {
    if (uuid == null)
    {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter, uuid cannot be null");
    }

    final long msbBigEndian = uuid.getMostSignificantBits();
    final long msbLittleEndian =
      ((msbBigEndian & 0x0000_00FF_0000_0000L) << 24) |
        ((msbBigEndian & 0x0000_FF00_0000_0000L) << 8) |
        ((msbBigEndian & 0x00FF_0000_0000_0000L) >>> 8) |
        ((msbBigEndian & 0xFF00_0000_0000_0000L) >>> 24) |
        ((msbBigEndian & 0x0000_0000_FF00_0000L) >>> 8) |
        ((msbBigEndian & 0x0000_0000_00FF_0000L) << 8) |
        ((msbBigEndian & 0x0000_0000_0000_FF00L) >>> 8) |
        ((msbBigEndian & 0x0000_0000_0000_00FFL) << 8);
    return new UUID(msbLittleEndian, uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
  }
```